# Angular 5 Firebase Database querying

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show specific data in one component from another component data select.

For example :

Database :

```
post {
name: string;
description: string;
photoURL: string;

      postInner {
      oneExample: string;
      twoExample: string;
      }

}
```

1. I got home.component and I am showing there all posts (name, description, photoUrl).
2. I click on one of the posts and I go to another component (post inner component) .
3. I get that post data on which I clicked postInner(oneExample, twoExample).

I am new to it, never done it, so clear explanation about it would be very helpful.

How to get data from the selected database object/list and transfer it to another component?

Comment: you can either use service or input decorator

Comment: Sorry, but I asked more information, because I want to know how to do that clearly and hope so someone will explain.